# Установка Ubuntu с графическим интерфейсом через Vagrant

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vagrant

Смотрел уроки, документацию и примеры 
Не могу понять - возможно ли с помощью Vagranta установить виртуалку не с консольным управлением, а с полным графическим интерфейсом? 
Как я понял - нельзя. Но все еще не уверен.

Comment: а что вообще мешает это сделать? o_O

Comment: Ну я скорее всего не особо умный, и каждый раз у меня запускается исключительно командная строка:C

При скачивании любого образа с офф сайта (https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search)
Выходит работать только в терминале

Comment: что именно ты делаешь? единственное, что может пойти не так — то что ты устанавливаешь «серверную» коробку без гуйни и ожидаешь, что она сама собой появится... в таком случае или выбери коробку, где она установлена из коробки (хороший каламбур); или установи нужный пакет постфактум скриптом, как описано [здесь](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/provisioning.html)

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен